TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] when sending Email from Gmail to myself
I am currently following tutorials to try to send emails from Gmail using smtplib. I keep getting the error:
TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
I am afraid that this might be something to do with Gmail updating its security to prevent people using App Passwords on Google accounts.
Any help much appreciated.
Here is the code I followed, the password was generated using the App Passwords function on Gmail:
import smtplib 
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

password = "XXXXXXXXX"
subject = "Email Subject"
body = "This is the body of the text message"
sender = "myemail@gmail.com"
recipients = sender
def send_email(subject, body, sender, recipients, password):
    msg = MIMEText(body)
    msg\["subject"\] = subject
    msg\["From"\] = sender
    msg\["To"\] = ",".join(recipients)

    with smtplib.SMTP_SSL("smtp.gmail.com", 465) as smtp_server:
        smtp_server.login(sender, password)
        smtp_server.sendmail(sender, recipients,msg.as_string())
    print("Message Sent!")

send_email(subject, body, sender, recipients, password)

As described, every time I try to run it, I get the error:
TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

As an aside, it looks like your email code was written for an older Python version. The email module in the standard library was overhauled in Python 3.6 to be more logical, versatile, and succinct; new code should target the (no longer very) new EmailMessage API. Probably throw away this code and start over with modern code from the Python email examples documentation.

Anyway, your Python code is not valid (you have backslashes in weird places). On the desktop version of this site, paste your code, then select the pasted block and type ctrl-K to correctly format your code with indentations preserved.

It's not necessarily due to security settings.
I was just able to use an app password to sign in to my gmail account.
The error message suggest you may be facing a network issue.
As it's not receiving a server error response. I.E

535, b'5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. For more information, go to\n5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials 41be03b00d2f7-7274907454esm1305271a12.61 - gsmtp

Or 451 connection timeout. https://support.google.com/a/answer/3726730?hl=en&sjid=635845508349629735-NC#:~:text=error%20messages.-,451,-4.4.2
I recommend you to try testing with the terminal in your python environment.
For example,
Using openssl:
openssl s_client -ign_eof -connect smtp.gmail.com:465
...
220 smtp.gmail.com 

Using telnet:
telnet smtp.gmail.com 465
...
Connected to smtp.gmail.com

This should show you if your client is able to establish a connection with the server.
According to Google's documentation the deprecation date for less secure apps is on September 2024. https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en
Although you can also get ahead of the curve and switch to OAuth authentication.
https://developers.google.com/gmail/imap/xoauth2-protocol#smtp_protocol_exchange
This requires generating an access token first. For which you should be able to use python client libraries, Google recommends familiarizing with the protocol as well. If you're already creating user tokens you might as well switch to using the gmail api since you're halfway there already, which would forego SMTP altogether.
Using OAuth 2.0 to Access Google APIs
https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2
Gmail API Python Quickstart
https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/python
If you do have a network issue, you'll still need to resolve it if you aim to use SMTP with access tokens. There are plenty of resources online on troubleshooting network issues.
You can begin with the test above to see if the timeout still occurs. Then check if the port is open for your client and review firewall settings and perform a traceroute.
Some additional references on this regard.
https://linux.die.net/man/8/traceroute
https://www.ionos.com/digitalguide/server/security/checking-open-ports/
Hope this helps!
